# Obscure UK comedy sci-fi sitcom from around 30-35 years Zadog or Zardok?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember this was a very funny programme with Zadog, or Zardok in the title?

It was sci-fi but I can't remember anything else about it.

Comment: Zardoz was hilarious, but not a sitcom. https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjA5OTQ5NTY0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjUzNTU3MTE@._V1_.jpg

Comment: Can't see any obvious matches in the 1970s https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_series&release_date=1970-01-01,1979-12-31&sort=alpha,desc

Comment: @Valorum made me feel old to realize this, but even 35 years ago would be end of 1988, so most likely a 90s show

Comment: Or the 80s and 90s: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=tv_series&release_date=1980-01-01,1990-12-31&sort=alpha,desc

Comment: @Logoleptica Just on the off chance, you aren't perhaps misremembering the name Zaphod from the TV series of The HitchHikers Guide to the Galaxy are you?

Comment: here is a clip of Zaphod in action from the BBC TV show from the 1980s so it fits your time frame... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxEqIt-NUSY

Comment: I'm somehow having trouble stretching my mind all the way from *HHGTTG* to "obscure," but these days who knows?

Comment: @DavidW Over here we only knew the books. I only learned it started out as a radio serial when a UK friend told me in the late 1990s.

Comment: @skyjack no, it definitely wasn't Zaphod. It was on weekly and quite colourful. I've been racking my brain for years about this but don't have enough details to look it up. So I was hoping that maybe someone else watched it too and remembered.

Comment: @Logoleptica well at least we managed to scrub that one from the list. There really weren't that many sf comedy shows though... Galloping Galaxies was for kids and really wasn't funny, Captain Sep Space Detective was colourful but not a comedy. Red Dwarf has no characters with a name resembling Zardok...Was it live action? Animated? Puppets? Did you watch it in the UK? If so can you remember what channel it was on? any clue like this would help.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: Pushing a bit, but the *Mrs.Black and the Blitmen* inserts in *Do Not Adjust Your Set*, starring The Bonzo Dog Doo Dah Band. ?  That was the late '60s.

Comment: @Logoleptica are you perhaps looking for The Adventure Game? It was basically a game show with a few framing dramatic elements all with a science fiction theme. Some of the character names come very close to those you mention in your title. According to the wikipedia entry character names include Gandor, Rongad and Angord. read about it here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventure_Game

Comment: @Logoleptica take a look at this, see if it rings any bells... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG-Ktm9n77s

Answer (score 3):

could it be Kinvig?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinvig

> Ineffectual dreamer Des Kinvig (Tony Haygarth) runs a rundown little electrical repair shop in the small town of Bingleton where he lives with his mumsy, scatterbrained wife Netta (Patsy Rowlands) and oversized pet dog Cuddly.

> One day his shop is visited by the beautiful, sharp-tongued Miss Griffin (Prunella Gee) who seems at first just another dissatisfied customer.

> However, after encountering a flying saucer while walking the dog one night, Kinvig discovers she is actually a scantily-clad alien from the planet Mercury who desperately needs the help of the scruffy, bearded Des' "exceptional brain" to stop an invasion of the evil ant-like Xux who are replacing people with robot duplicates.

> Kinvig's friend Jim Piper (Colin Jeavons) is a lifelong UFO watcher and wild-eyed conspiracy buff who is consumed by jealousy when Des tells him about his extraterrestrial exploits.

> It is left intentionally ambiguous whether Kinvig's experiences with aliens are real or the product of an overactive imagination.